# Is there a file limitation for Xalan 2.7.1 running on Java 1.8 and Ubuntu 16?

Tags: java, ubuntu, xslt, xalan

I'm observing the following: my Java 1.8 application (web app on Tomcat 8) is running on Ubuntu 16 under a user that has a ulimit of 65000.

A certain application logic within the Java app is looping through 80000 different files. When this loop is performed in Java code, there is no issue. When I run the loop via XSLT by using the `document()` function (Xalan 2.7), it stops opening files after 32000, depending on the current load on our system. By stopping I mean that XSL can not access the content of the requested file.

I'm wondering if there is a limitation besides the `ulimit` of Ubuntu.

Any hints are welcome.

Comment: So you have a single stylesheet trying to open 80000 different files during a single stylesheet execution? Perhaps Xalan simply runs out of memory as an XSLT processor normally does not release a document tree once loaded and parsed.

Comment: 'By stopping I mean that Xalan cannot access the content of the requested file', but what exactly do you mean by 'cannot access'?